# Mysqli, add the contents of a column and display the results

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

I am trying to add together the contents of 3 columns in my database and then display the results, but I think my code is a bit flaky as it doesn't seem to be doing a lot.

I just get an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\easyphp\www\cusmgr\jobsmanager.php on line 160"

```
 $query = $db->query("SELECT SUM(pricequoted) pricequotedtotal,SUM(partprice)     partpricetotal,SUM(profit) profittotal FROM `content`");
$result = $query->fetch_object();
$pricequoted = "{$result->pricequotedtotal}";
$partprice = "{$result->partpricetotal}";
$profit = "{$result->profittotal}";
echo 'Quoted Total : &pound;'.$pricequoted;
echo 'Parts Total : &pound;'.$partprice;
 echo 'Quoted Total : &pound;'.$profit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli::query` returns false to you which is non-object indeed.

This is a sign of error.

Please add this:

```
if (!$query)
    echo $db->error . "\n";
```

after `$db->query` and post the output here.

Comment: Table 'customermanager.content' doesn't exist 
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\easyphp\www\cusmgr\jobsmanager.php on line 162

Comment: @IainSimpson: this pretty much explains the error, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes !, thats what I get from copying code from another project iv completed argh, not changing the table column names !. :-S